# Excel has unreadable content when opening a workbook saved by openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm new to python and openpyxl, I've written the simplest of scripts using openpyxl (v2.0.4) on the Ubuntu OS. The script opens an existing excel workbook and then saves it again.

```vb
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
wb.save('filename.xlsx')
```

When attempting to open the workbook in excel 2007 on a Windows OS, I'm getting an error saying there is unreadable content.

Apologies if this is a very basic fix, as I am extremely new to this field.

Comment: Could you open file in excel before you use `openpyxl` ?

Comment: Hi, yes the file could open in excel before being loaded and saved using openpyxl

Comment: I have read a few other questions that had similar problems, that looked like the issue was related to encoding, however I checked mine and python is using utf-8, and I have not even written any strings. So I'm still stumped

Comment: Need more information to be able to help. If possible submit a bug with a sample file to the bugtracker so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Unreadable content error message is due to the

> references

in **Formulas->Name Manager**. By removing all of the references, saving to a new workbook should be error free.